# Resolving render return for React Component for Clappr

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a component for the Clapper Video player.  Here is my component:

```
// @flow

import React from 'react';
import Clappr from 'clappr';

class ClapprPlayer extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.change(this.props.source);
  }

   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const changed = (nextProps.source !== this.props.source);
    this.props = nextProps;
    this.state = nextState;
    if (changed) {
      this.change(nextProps.source);
    }
    return false;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.destroyPlayer();
  }

  props: {
    source: string
  };

  destroyPlayer() {
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.destroy();
    }
    this.player = null;
  }

  change(source) {
    if (this.player) {
      this.destroyPlayer();
    }
    this.player = new Clappr.Player({
      parent: this.refs.player,
      source: source,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      hlsjsConfig: {
        enableWorker: true
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref="player"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default ClapprPlayer;
```

When compiling in webpack I have a few errors:

```
  42:15  error  Using this.refs is deprecated                      
react/no-string-refs
  43:7   error  Expected property shorthand                            
object-shorthand
  55:9   error  Empty components are self-closing                      
react/self-closing-comp
  55:14  error  Using string literals in ref attributes is deprecated  
react/no-string-refs
```

So the issue is I can't use things like:

```
parent: this.refs.player
```

Strangely enough, it doesn't like this either for some reason?

```
source: source
```

Should it be?

```
source: {source}
```

And we are pretty much out to lunch in the render() function because it's using refs as well.

On my details page I render the component like so:

```
<div>
  <ClapprPlayer 
   source="http://www.streambox.fr/playlists/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8" />
</div>
```

Wondering if you guys see what I am doing wrong?  Need to figure out a replacement for the depreacted stuff.  I am not clear on how to return the component so it shows the video player.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you should be able to use `document.getElementById("player")` instead of `this.refs.player`

your code will look like this

```
return (
      <div>
        <div id="player"></div>
      </div>
    );
```

and for your method

```
this.player = new Clappr.Player({
      parent: document.getElementById("player"),
      source: source,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      hlsjsConfig: {
        enableWorker: true
      }
    });
```

if you test it and it did work please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use string value fir refs, use a function instead. Like this: `ref={node => this.node = node}`. Now you can use it inside `componentDidMount` as `this.node` as parent.